# how to submit 2 forms with one button rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I want to submit two forms with a single button.

Below if my code :-

**rate.rb**

```
belongs_to :target, :polymorphic => true
belongs_to :location
```

**location.rb**

```
has_many :rates
```

**event.rb**

```
has_many :rates, :as => :target
```

**form.html.haml**

```
= form_for [@event, @rate] do |form|
                    %ul
                        %li= form.radio_button :rate, "Excellent"
                        %li Excellent
                        %li= form.radio_button :rate, "Okay"
                        %li Okay
                        %li= form.radio_button :rate, "Poorly organized"
                        %li Poorly organized
                        %li= form.radio_button :rate, "Didn't happen"
                        %li Didn't happen

=form_for [@event.location, @rate] do |form|
                    %ul
                        %li= form.radio_button :rate, "Excellent"
                        %li Excellent
                        %li= form.radio_button :rate, "Okay"
                        %li Okay
                        %li= form.radio_button :rate, "Nothing special"
                        %li Nothing special
```

How can this be done ?

Comment: You can't, without submitting at least one form by AJAX.

Comment: What is the AJAX solution for this ?

Comment: It really is unclear why you would want to do this. Take a look at [nested attributes](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html) instead

Comment: nested attributes would have worked if I had one model referring to two models, eg :- event has_many :rates, :locations, then I could have used fields_for, can you use fields_for in my case ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was in same situation today and did:

in form.html.haml add a link: (I wrote in ERB)

```
<%= link_to "Save", "#", :class => 'button_submit' %>
```

Assuming form ids as "form1" and "form2" in some coffee file:

rates.js.coffee

```
jQuery ->
  $(".button_submit").live "click", (e) ->
    e.preventDefault()
    $("#form1").trigger "submit"
    $("#form2").trigger "submit"
```

That's it!